# Mysql - Slow query output

Tags: mysql, formatting

I got the slowquery log running from my amazon RDS instances and I'm able to retrieve them using a custom script in the "sloquery.log" format.

My question is quite simple, is there any formatting program out there able to make thoses reports more "readable".

Current output is something like this :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/RUew7gS.png]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, [`mysqldumpslow`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldumpslow.html) is available in all standard MySQL distributions.

Comment: Thanks ! Didn't though about this.

Answer (score 1):

I knocked up this crude php script to extract the log into CSV format, which means I can then easily manipulate it with a spreadsheet.

You will have to change the input and output locations probably (I just drag the log to my localhost and then run the script against it there).

```
<?php
set_time_limit(240);
$handle = fopen('C:\\Users\\kwalker\\Downloads\\mysql-slow.log', "rb");
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$inline = '';
$inline = fgets($handle, 8192);
$OutLine = array();
$OutLine['Time'] = 'Time';
$OutLine['Timestamp'] = 'Timestamp';
$OutLine['User'] = 'User';
$OutLine['Query_time'] = 'Query_time';
$OutLine['Lock_time'] = 'Lock_time';
$OutLine['Rows_sent'] = 'Rows_sent';
$OutLine['Rows_examined'] = 'Rows_examined';
$OutLine['Database'] = 'Database';
$OutLine['SqlOut'] = 'SqlOut';
WriteOut($fp, $OutLine);
$OutLine = array();
$OutLine['Time'] = '';
$OutLine['Timestamp'] = '';
$OutLine['User'] = '';
$OutLine['Query_time'] = '';
$OutLine['Lock_time'] = '';
$OutLine['Rows_sent'] = '';
$OutLine['Rows_examined'] = '';
$OutLine['Database'] = '';
$OutLine['SqlOut'] = '';
$PossibleUse = true;
$TimeTriggeredOut = true;
$CurrentTime = '';
$CurrentDatabase = '';

while (!feof($handle)) 
{
    switch (true)
    {
        case substr($inline, 0, 8) == '# Time: ' :
            WriteOut($fp, $OutLine);
            $PossibleUse = true;
            $Timings = explode(': ', $inline);
            $CurrentTime = $Timings[1];
            $OutLine = array();
            $OutLine['Time'] = $CurrentTime;
            $OutLine['Timestamp'] = '';
            $OutLine['User'] = '';
            $OutLine['Query_time'] = '';
            $OutLine['Lock_time'] = '';
            $OutLine['Rows_sent'] = '';
            $OutLine['Rows_examined'] = '';
            $OutLine['Database'] = $CurrentDatabase;
            $OutLine['SqlOut'] = '';
            $TimeTriggeredOut = true;
            break;
        case substr($inline, 0, 6) == '# User' :
            if (!$TimeTriggeredOut)
            {
                WriteOut($fp, $OutLine);
                $PossibleUse = true;
                $OutLine = array();
                $OutLine['Time'] = $CurrentTime;
                $OutLine['Timestamp'] = '';
                $OutLine['User'] = '';
                $OutLine['Query_time'] = '';
                $OutLine['Lock_time'] = '';
                $OutLine['Rows_sent'] = '';
                $OutLine['Rows_examined'] = '';
                $OutLine['Database'] = $CurrentDatabase;
                $OutLine['SqlOut'] = '';
            }
            $OutLine['User'] = $inline;
            $TimeTriggeredOut = false;
            break;
        case substr($inline, 0, 12) == '# Query_time' :
            $Timings = explode(' ', $inline);
            //print_r($Timings);
            $OutLine['Query_time'] = $Timings[2];
            $OutLine['Lock_time'] = $Timings[5];
            $OutLine['Rows_sent'] = $Timings[7];
            $OutLine['Rows_examined'] = $Timings[10];
            $PossibleUse = true;
            break;
        case substr($inline, 0, 14) == 'SET timestamp=' :
            $Timings = explode('=', $inline);
            $OutLine['Timestamp'] = $Timings[1];
            $PossibleUse = true;
            break;
        case $PossibleUse AND substr($inline, 0, 4) == 'use ' :
            $Timings = explode(' ', $inline);
            $CurrentDatabase = $Timings[1];
            $OutLine['Database'] = $CurrentDatabase;
            $PossibleUse = false;
            break;
        default;
            $OutLine['SqlOut'] .= $inline;
    }
    $inline = fgets($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($fp);
fclose($handle);

function WriteOut($fp, $OutLine)
{
    foreach($OutLine as &$aOutLine)
    {
        $aOutLine = str_replace("\n", " ", $aOutLine);
        $aOutLine = str_replace("\r", " ", $aOutLine);
        $aOutLine = str_replace("\t", " ", $aOutLine);
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $OutLine);
}
?>
```